# Using C# (HTML Razor), how can I not display specific HTML element if the returned value is null?

Tags: c#, razor

If ContactPerson is empty, then the card should not display. If it returns true, then display.

However, I think I'm missing something because when I return a null value, it's still displaying the card with the title "Contact Details"

Here's my code:

```
  @if (Model.Item.Fields.ContactPerson != null)
  {
    <div class="notice__card card mb-3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="notice__card--contact">Contact Details</h3>
        @foreach (var person in Model.Item.Fields.ContactPerson)
        {
          <p class="card-text">
            <span>@person.Fields.Name</span>
            <a href="tel:@person.Fields.Phone"><i class="bi bi-telephone-fill"></i> @person.Fields.Phone</a>
            <a href="@person.Fields.Email"><i class="bi bi-envelope-fill"></i> Email @person.Fields.Name</a>
          </p>
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
@foreach (var person in Model.Item.Fields.ContactPerson)
```

Suggests that the (misleadingly named) property `ContactPerson` is a collection.  So if this is `true`:

```
@if (Model.Item.Fields.ContactPerson != null)
```

And this never iterates:

```
@foreach (var person in Model.Item.Fields.ContactPerson)
```

Then what you have is not `null`, but an empty collection.  To describe it conceptually... An empty box is still a box.

It sounds like you want to test for `null` *and* an empty collection.  For example:

```
@if (Model.Item.Fields.ContactPerson != null && Model.Item.Fields.ContactPerson.Count() > 0)
```

Comment: You put me on the right track. I fixed it. Thanks.